# Call static method from string given class

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods

I have a JSON that user can modify outside my code.
In that, I have full class name like:

```
models.InputLoader.InputLoader
```

When I load it in code, I get this a string representation.
I want to call static method `unseralize` to which I pass another datum from JSON via dictionary.

```
InputLoader:
   @staticmethod
   def unserialize(d: Dict) -> InputLoader:
       return InputLoader(d["x"])

   def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x
```

In JSON:

```json
{
  "class": "models.InputLoader.InputLoader"
  "x": 45
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071/1814420)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: Have you used `__init__` without `self` ?

Comment: This is for methods that are from instance, not the static methods